# Count group by operation for intermediate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table generated like this

```
ShopItem.select("shop_items.label_id, shop_items.store_id")
```

with the cols `label_id: 7789, store_id: 4140`. Now I want to find out, for each label, how many stores belong to it. The result should be something like `{"label_id" => "number of stores for the label", ... }`

Can I anybody give me a hint how to do it?

(the dbms I use is PostgreSQL, and I am accessing it via Rails 3.2 ActiveRecord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

```
ShopItem.group(:store_id).count
```

It will return a Hash there the key is the `:store_id`, the value is the number.

```
{6323=>2, 31300=>1, 9631=>1}
```